# How to create multiple arrays from one text line?

Tags: java, arrays, input, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I'm a first year programming student, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

What I'm trying to do is read a text file that contains an answer key on line 1, and the proceeding lines will contain a student's ID number and their answers to a test. Here is an example:

```
TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT
ABC54301 TFTFTFTTTTF TFTFTFTT
ABC54302 TFFTFFFFFFFFTFTFTFTT
ABC54303 TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTTTTTT
ABC54304 TFFTTTFFTTFFTFTFTFTT
ABC54305 TFTFTFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT
```

My idea is to create three arrays - one that contains only the answer key, one that contains the students' ID numbers, and one that contains the studentss answers. The student ID number is always 8 digits long, but can possibly contain spaces. The student's answers are always 20 characters long, but can also contain spaces. So I can't split them based on spaces.

The instructions contained this:

```
 while (inFile.hasNext())
 {
   ...
 }

where 'inFile' is the Scanner object connected to the input file.

Each student's record should be read by two read's -- 
one string (for ID) and another string (answer string).
```

I'm pretty lost. My initial idea is to loop through each line past the first, and set each segment of the line to its complimentary array. The problem that I'm reaching is that I can't seem to find any instruction or clarification on how I would split the lines based on number of characters.

I was thinking maybe something like:

```
 while (inFile.hasNext())
 {
    // I would somehow set the first line to its own array
    // As the loop continues, as long as its not the first line
    idNums[i] =     //Characters 1-8
    studentAnswers[i] =     //Characters 10-30
 }
```

Is that reasonable? Or is there an easier way? I feel like I'm approaching this in a manner more complicated than is necessary.

EDIT:

After learning more about maps and regex, I've attempted several different versions of this code. The first consisted of:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] studentInfo = scan.nextLine().split(" ", 2);
    info.put(studentInfo[0], studentInfo[1]);
}
```

Which kind of worked, but the problem is that if it ended with spaces, it wouldn't save the full 20 characters. Is that an issue? I'm not sure. Currently I'm testing this:

```
String[] answerKey = scan.nextLine().split("");

Map<String, String[]> results = new HashMap<>();
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    results.put(line.substring(0, 8), line.substring(9).split(""));
}
```

Which is giving me the correct keys, but incorrect values. The values seem to be pointing to memory locations. For example:

```
{ABC54339=[Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302
```

Answer (score 0):

First read line 1 before the while loop. You can turn that into an array like this:

```
String[] answers = inFile.nextLine().split("");
```

FYI that regex tells split to split between every character.

Then to read in the results, you're better off keeping the student id and their answers together - a map is an obvious choice, as it stores key/value pairs, but also because it grows automatically.

Use substring to get the first 8 chars of the line and also to get the results, and `put()` them in the map. Store the result value as an array, created using the same split call above.

```
Map<String, String[]> results = new HashMap<>();
while ...
    results.put(line.substring(0, 8), line.substring(9).split(""));
```

FYI if you're using java 8, you can do it in one line (ie without a loop), although its a bit of a train wreck:

```
Map<String, String[]> results = StreamSupport
  .stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(inFile, 0))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.substring(0, 8), s -> s.substring(9).split(""));
```

---

As an aside, if your teacher gave you to initial code for you to fill out, it clearly shows he or she has poor software design skill; the scanner variable should not have the word "file" in it, because it operates on an input stream, not just a file input stream - for example your code could run over input from the command line. The code shouldn't know, care or suggest a particular source of the input: `scanner` or simply `in` would be better choices.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't learned about maps yet - but hearing that from a couple of users here, that will be how I approach this problem. Would you mind providing a small bit of skeleton code or pseudo-code  to give an example of how a map would work in this sort of case? I'm using Java 8.

Comment: I think I am making a simple mistake, but I can't see what it is. I've been studying maps and regex for the last couple of hours - maybe I've been looking at this for too long, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong. 

Will update the original post with new code. I tried it in comments and it doesn't work - oops!

Comment: with java 8 you can just use a blank regex `""` to split every character - don't study regex yet (it will fry your brain). Ignore the java 8 code - that was just for interest. Try the simple loop - it should work. After the loop print the map to see if it's worked. You can then iterate over the map by iterating over `map.entrySet()`

Answer (score 0):

Since your instructions explicitly say that you should make 2 reads, The best way I've found after reading [This Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to fulfill those instructions is with [Scanner.Next(string)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.lang.String%29)

It looks like the "pattern" parameter expects a regular expression, http://rubular.com/ is a great resource for experimenting with regular expressions, and it also has a reference for basic regex syntax.

For your convenience, the regular expression for matching 8 characters is this `".{8}"`

If you do use regular expression, make sure that you escape all your `\`s that you use for the regex escape sequence(on escape for java and 1 for the regex language), so to match a numeric digit, you have to use `"\\d"`

Comment: Thanks for linking the documentation and the link! I'll be sure to look into those resources. We haven't yet learned about regex, so I'll be learning while I solve this problem. The chapter content for this problem was regarding arrays.

Comment: After a couple hours of experimentation, I can't seem to get regex to work properly. I need it to stop after only a certain amount of characters, but the delimiter you recommended (".{8}") doesn't seem to work. Spaces work, but I need to retain spaces. I'm stumped right now, but I'll keep working at it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the first line into a string and leave it as a string (The string is an array of characters).  Read the remaining lines and store them in a Map using the student's ID as the key (use line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" ")) and the rest of the line (string) as the value to the Map (line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") + 1).  The +1 is to skip the space.

Now you can just go through your Map and compare each student's (string) answer to your answer key

```
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    // Make sure you don't step out of bounds of the array for student's answer
    // Any answers not checked will be considered wrong
    if (i < studentsAnswer.Length)
    { 
        if (studentsAnswer.charAt(i) != answer.charAt(1)) 
        {
            numberOfIncorrect = numberOfIncorrect + 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        numberOfIncorrect = numberOfIncorrect + 1;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what Maps are yet, but even just having the correct terminology to research helps me greatly.

Comment: I edited my original post. The idea of saving the first line into a string worked perfectly - but I'm stumped while trying to get the keys/values into the Map correctly. Perhaps I'm just stuck on syntax?

Comment: The second parameter of your map doesn't need to be a string array, just make it a string (Map<string, string>).  Then when you put the key/value into your map, you don't need to split on the value (results.put(line.substring(0, 8), line.substring(9)).  After you have all that, just go through all the key/value pairs in your map and you can use my snippet in my answer to check results.